# How update the database using a web service and EclipseLink as JPA provider?

Tags: java, database, web-services, jpa, eclipselink

I have done a simple web service using EclipseLink as JPA provider. I am a beginner when coming to JPA, so I am wondering if this is the common way and most pure and secure way to make updates to the database:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()){
       em.getTransaction().begin();
   }
   Query query = (Query)em.createNamedQuery("Person.updatePerson");
   query.setParameter("personId", person.getPersonPK().getPersonId())
        .setParameter("personName", name);
   return query.executeUpdate();
```

Why don't I need to use `em.getTransaction().commit();` after I have called `em.getTransaction().begin()`? `query.executeUpdate()` seems to update the database, not the commit call. Why is that so? What is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call commit() to commit the transaction.  Executing a query will not commit.

What type of transactions are you using?  JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL?  If you are using JTA, then you must use JTA to begin a commit transactions.

Enable logging to get more details.

In general in JPA updates are normally done by reading the object and using its set methods, not executing raw queries.

Comment: But `query.executeUpdate();` seems to update the database even without the commit. If I insteaf of using the Query I can just call EntityManager.merge(), then I have to call commit() to commit the transaction, but I don´t know what the best way is to update the database.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, I did some investigation with a non-jta-datasource:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit1");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
// database: t.name='OLD'
Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Test t set t.name = 'NEW'");
query.executeUpdate();
// database: t.name='OLD'
TypedQuery<String> tq 
    = em.createQuery("SELECT t.name from Test t", String.class);
System.out.println(tq.getSingleResult()); 
// output: 'NEW'
// database: t.name='OLD'
em.getTransaction().commit();
// database: t.name='NEW'
```

My explanation approach (please correct me, if I am wrong):

1. The database holds 'OLD' value until `em.getTransaction().commit()`.
2. The SELECT query returns 'NEW' from persistence context

Comment: This is what James said in the prior answer.  Your change is done in the scope of the current transaction and is only visible within it until the transaction commits.  The EntityManager is using the same connection/transaction and so can see the changes - other EMs and connections cannot until the transaction commits.